# Shell Script runs when manually triggered but does nto exicute when Cron runs it

Tags: bash, cron

**UPDATE** After writing out the cron process per Gordon's comment on this post, it seems that Cron cannot find the script. Any guidance on this would be appreciated.

```
>>/tmp/HRsnapshot.log 2>&1 
/bin/sh: 1: /home/user/Scripts/HRsnapshot.sh: not found
/bin/sh: 1: /home/user/Scripts/HRsnapshot.sh: not found
/bin/sh: 1: /home/user/Scripts/HRsnapshot.sh: not found
```

---

I need some assistance in understanding why a cronjob is not executing a script that runs as designed when executed manually from the user account.

Currently, the configuration is as such.

Crontab

```
#Download HR File from Google and push it to HR Server via SFTP
38 11 * * * BASH_ENV=/home/user/Scripts/preload.sh /home/user/Scripts/HRsnapshot.sh
```

We are loading user env variables in the preload.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash


    export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
    . /etc/profile
    . ~/.bashrc
    
    export GAMCFGDIR="/home/user2/GAMConfig"
```

The Bash profile has some callouts in it to an application named GAM

```
#Setting for Gam Config
export GAMCFGDIR="/home/user2/GAMConfig"

export PATH

alias gam="/home/user2/bin/gamadv-xtd3/gam"
```

The primary script is designed to download a file using GAM (Python app that simplifies API calls to Google Cloud for a Google Workspace env)

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/user/Scripts

/home/user2/bin/gamadv-xtd3/gam user 'hellodolly@conso.org' get drivefile id '1S4tkzS2lIj360-WFhTy3FBm6kZ7hsL4PvO7PdikffiidI' format 'csv'  targetfolder /home/user/SFTP/daily_export/ targetname 'FY2022_HR_Form.csv' overwrite

sshpass -p '*jndn4Kz#8Rwrj' sftp GoogleSFTP@10.0.0.0<<EOF
cd /D:/SFTPRoot/Google_Workflows
put  /home/user/SFTP/daily_export/FY2022_HR_Form.csv
exit
EOF
```

Cronlog

```
Oct 15 13:07:01 JUMPBOX CRON[5431]: (user) CMD (BASH_ENV=/home/user/Scripts/preload.sh /home/user/Scripts/HRsnapshot.sh)
```

Here is what the user's env looks like

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
SUDO_GID=1000
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/su user
SUDO_USER=user2
PWD=/home/user/Scripts
LOGNAME=user
HOME=/home/user
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2
GAMCFGDIR=/home/user2/GAMConfig
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
TERM=xterm-256color
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
USER=user
LC_TERMINAL_VERSION=3.4.16
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
SUDO_UID=1000
MAIL=/var/mail/user
OLDPWD=/home/user2
```

All user names, IP addresses, Emails Addresses, and Passwords have been obfuscated

Comment: Standard cron troubleshooting: capture the output & errors from the job by adding something like `>>/tmp/HRsnapshot.log 2>&1` to the crontab line, then examine the log for info about what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Now I am even more confused. The output is indicating that the script cannot be found

/bin/sh: 1: /home/user/Scripts/HRsnapshot.sh: not found

Comment: Perhaps the OP obfuscateth too much.

Comment: FWIW aliases are not expanded in noninteractive scripts. The alias seems unimportant here, but probably remove it from your noninteractive configuration just to keep your own head straight. A function would work for both interactive and noninteractive scenarios (and anyway, functions are superior to aliases in many ways).

Comment: @MikeReilly Very strange. At this point, I'd be checking for typos or weird/nonprinting characters in either the crontab entry, scriptname, or script contents. I like `cat -vt` for making nonprinting characters visible, e.g. `crontab -l | cat -vt` and `cat -vt /home/user/Scripts/HRsnapshot.sh`. If that doesn't find anything, try moving the script to a more ... basic location (I'd actually try putting it in /tmp, and see if it can find it there).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your preload script, export your PATH after sourcing the files.

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/profile
. ~/.bashrc
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
    
export GAMCFGDIR="/home/user2/GAMConfig"
```

When `sshpass` is in `/usr/local/bin` you don't want the path changed by `/etc/profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thank you Walter. I have made the change, but now I am seeing that crom cannot see the script to run it. Trying to figure out this piece now.

`/bin/sh: 1: /home/dpmacrina/Scripts/HRsnapshot.sh: not found`

Comment: Are you sure that `Scripts` is not in lowercase? What do you have after `ls -l /home/dpmacrina/Scripts/HRsnapshot.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone for your help.

Strangest thing. There is something invisible in the copied text for the cronjob that is causing the error.

```
38 11 * * * BASH_ENV=/home/dpmacrina/Scripts/preload.sh /home/dpmacrina/Scripts/HRsnapshot.sh
03 06 * * * BASH_ENV=/home/dpmacrina/Scripts/preload.sh /home/dpmacrina/Scripts/HRSnapshot.sh
```

These are the two lines that are in the crontab. The top is what was failing, the bottom is what I typed in new. The bottom works.